# How do I iterate searching for a list element in another list in Python?

Tags: python, csv, iteration

I want to search for elements of namelist in banklist, and if an element is found in banklist, return that element as well as the element after it.

So for example:
Namelist: 'John Doe', 'Jack Black'.
Banklist: 'John Doe', '9134', 'Richard Pitt', '1652', 'Jack Black', '9145', 'Bob Brand', '6523'

I want this returned: 'John Doe,9134', 'Jack Black,9145'

To this end, I have written the following. It works, but I don't know how to iterate it, so that it searches for all the elements that overlap, instead of stopping after the first.

Result: 'John Doe,9134'.
Desired result: 'John Doe,9134', 'Jack Black,9145'.

```
f = open('namelist.txt', 'r')
namestring = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('testsheet.csv', 'r')
bankstring = f.read()
f.close()

namestring = namestring.replace(", ", ",")
namelist = namestring.split(",")

banklist = bankstring.split("\n")
bankstring = ','.join(banklist)
banklist = bankstring.split(",")

n = banklist.index(namelist[1])
res = banklist[n] + "," + banklist[n+1]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying the problem, using the `enumerate` on the `bank_list` and printing the name and the number if the element from it exists in the `name_list`:

```
name_list = ['John Doe', 'Jack Black']
bank_list = ['John Doe', '9134', 'Richard Pitt', '1652', 'Jack Black', '9145', 'Bob Brand', '6523']

for ind, elem in enumerate(bank_list):
    if elem in name_list:
        print(elem, bank_list[ind + 1])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
John Doe 9134                                                                                                                 
Jack Black 9145
```

Comment: Sorry I wanted to ask another question but it didn't work in a comment. Could you look at the edit please?

Comment: @user2296226 there is nothing in the edit, if you want to ask another question please make it a separate one! Would love to help again cheers ^^